# I want to get price according user location how can i do that by flutter shopify app

Tags: flutter

I want to get price and unit price  according user location how can i do that by  flutter shopify app

i try to set location using Geolocation package

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. You're supposed to ask questions about how to solve more practical problems with a concrete approach. This question is too broad and is unclear what you actually want.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.